# Como abrir página na mesma aba com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse script `ajax` que atualiza a tela e chama o `notifyMe()`
e a notificação é exibida. Mas percebi que ao clicar ele abre a página em outra aba. Quero que quando seja clicado na notificação ele abra na mesma aba que foi executada esta notificação e não que seja aberto uma nova.

```
<script>
    // request permission on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

function notifyMe() {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
  else {
    var notification = new Notification('DIAZERO SECURITY', {
      icon: '<?php url(); ?>/favicon.png',
      body: "Sua solicitação foi atualizada!",
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("<?php url(); ?>/solicitacao/<?php echo $a; ?>");      
    };

  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/location) no lugar de `window.open`:

```
window.location.href = "<?php url(); ?>/solicitacao/<?php echo $a; ?>";
```

Comment: opa muito bom resolveu muito obrigado ^^